# BTC Withdrawal from Crypto-Bridge

Tags: exchanges, decentralized-exchanges

I did a small transaction as a test.  I wanted to convert BTS (BitShares) to LTC (LiteCoin).  Couldn't find any direct exchange, so traded a token amount to BTC on Crypto-Bridge, then tried a withdrawal to Coinbase.

This is the transaction: 
https://cryptofresh.com/u/neal-walters-bridge

This is the screenshot of what i entered: 
[image]

Even though I entered my CoinBase receive address, the above shows I sent to CryptoBridge.  Is just a matter of waiting for it to convert and send, or did I do something wrong.  Obviously I want to verify before doing a larger amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BTC arrived within an hour or so.  A little scary, but it worked. The above link never shows that Crypto-bridge send the funds, so I guess they convert it and generate a new transaction.

Comment: Just adding this comment for future readers: It takes some time for CryptoBridge to execute orders: (which can be tracked by checking for burn assets here: https://wallet.crypto-bridge.org/account/cryptobridge/dashboard). Then the actual transfer also takes time. BTC takes around an hour to confirm, others like LTC, ETH take minutes.